# How does Electron flow in Daniell cells in series look like?

Tags: electrochemistry

After taking a look at this question: [What causes the flow of electrons from anode to cathode in a Daniell cell?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/710764/what-causes-the-flow-of-electrons-from-anode-to-cathode-in-a-daniell-cell/710778#710778?newreg=cddff3ef30e7429891940c1c6f6f74dd) i was quite satisfied with answer provided there. One question that remained for me was how the electron flow would look in 2 of those cells in series. What would happen there to establish a new total net Voltage ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about galvanic cells combined in a series. The electron flow follows the same rules as for general power sources linked in a series.

Each cell in such a series can be evaluated independently on the others, that are taken just as power sources.